# how to get object's attributes

Tags: android, string, object

How can I get an object's attributes?
I created an object that has two fields, first one called Title containing the string value "title1" and second one called Description containing the string value "description1". I would like to get the strings inside.
The method item.toString() gets me the two strings one after the other. Is there a way to get the strings separatively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create accessor methods for each field.
Assuming you have declared your fields like this:

```
private String title;
private String desciption;
```

create the accessor methods in your class definition like this:

```
public String getTitle() {
     return title;
}

public String getDescription() {
     return description;
}
```

then you just call these methods to get the appropriate value.

Comment: Although not incorrect, Android docs suggest avoid using getters/setter methods :s

`Avoid Internal Getters/Setters`:
http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html

Comment: It's not that it's not recommended at all  They've told that it's not recommended for just internal calls.

Answer (score 0):

Class Declaration

```
public class Class_Name {
    private String Category;
    private String Category_Type;

    public Class_Name () {
        super();
    }

    public Class_Name(String Category, String Category_Type) {
        super();
        this.Category = Category;
        this.Category_Type = Category_Type;
    }

    /*public Class_Name (String Category_Type) {
        this.Category_Type = Category_Type;
    }*/

    public String getCategory() {
        return Category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String Category) {
        this.Category = Category;
    }

    public String getCategory_Type() {
        return Category_Type;
    }

    public void setCategory_Type(String Category_Type) {
        this.Category_Type = Category_Type;
    }
}
```

In the class where you should use this Object to store and retrieve values.

```
//Create an object for this class

private Class_Name data;

// To save values

data.setCategory(sCategory);
data.setCategory_Type(sType);

// To retrieve values

String sCategory = data.getCategory();
String sType = data.getCategory_Type();
```